# Subset Data frame to plot iGraph in R

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph, subset

I'm working on the Data frame shown below.

```
  S.no                tmp     size
     1               tmp1      100
     2         tmp2, tmp3      200
     3   tmp1, tmp2, tmp3       50
```

What I want to do is plot an igraph graph in which is each tmp is a vertex and coming to edges, the tmp values in each row will have a edge to rest of the tmp values in that specific row.
Node size is proportional to the size column.
The size of node tmp1 will should be 150 (100+50) similarly tmp2 should have node size 250(200+50).

I've tried this way, 
Subset the data frame.

```
df <- table[3,2]  
df                               # gives output as "tmp1, tmp2, tmp3"  
class(df)                        # data frame  
df <- gsub(", ",":",df)  
df                               # gives output as "tmp1:tmp2:tmp3"  
graph <- graph.formula(df:df)    # graph.formula(:) to map every vertex
                                 # to other vertices.
```

When i do this I get a a single node in the graph i.e its taking character df as a vertex.
I've tried Explicitly coercing the df to character type, list type by using as.list(), as.character()
but it didn't work.

I've gone through graph.data.frame() function manual in graph website but couldn't understand how to 
input the vertex data in column way.

I was stuck here for several hours, i'm a novice here. Please help!

Comment: Could you please use a reproducible example (i.e. a built in dataset)?

Comment: Based on the logic i made this dataset as a sample. @Hack-R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your sample data in an R-friendly form

```
df <- data.frame(
    S.no = 1:3, 
    tmp = c("tmp1", "tmp2, tmp3", "tmp1, tmp2, tmp3"), 
    size = c(100, 200, 50), stringsAsFactors=F
)
```

First I want to expand the `tmp` column so there is one value per row

```
ddf<-with(df, do.call(rbind, 
    Map(cbind.data.frame, S.no=S.no, tmp=strsplit(tmp, ", "), size=size)
))
```

#

```
   S.no  tmp size
# 1    1 tmp1  100
# 2    2 tmp2  200
# 3    2 tmp3  200
# 4    3 tmp1   50
# 5    3 tmp2   50
# 6    3 tmp3   50
```

Now I can assemble the edge list based on the S.no group number

```
el <- do.call(rbind, Filter(length, lapply(split(ddf$tmp, ddf$S.no), function(x) 
    if (length(x)>=2) t(combn(as.character(x),2)) )))

#      [,1]   [,2]  
# [1,] "tmp2" "tmp3"
# [2,] "tmp1" "tmp2"
# [3,] "tmp1" "tmp3"
# [4,] "tmp2" "tmp3"
```

Basically we are just looking for groups with at least two nodes, then taking all possible combinations of those vertices to make an edge list per groups, then we bind everything together.

Finally we calculate the node sizes using aggregate

```
vx <- aggregate(size~tmp, ddf, sum)

#    tmp size
# 1 tmp1  150
# 2 tmp2  250
# 3 tmp3  250
```

Now we just put it together in graph form

```
gg <- graph.edgelist(el, FALSE)
V(gg)[as.character(vx[,1])]$size <- vx[,2]
plot(gg)
```

[image]

You will probably want to re-scale the sizes to something a bit more reasonable to see the edges

```
torange<-function(x, new.min=25, new.max=50) {
    (x-min(x))/diff(range(x)) * (new.max-new.min) + new.min
}    
V(gg)$size <- torange(V(gg)$size)
plot(gg)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `cSplit`

```
 library(data.table)
 library(devtools)
 source_gist(11380733) 

df <- data.frame(
S.no = 1:3, 
tmp = c("tmp1", "tmp2, tmp3", "tmp1, tmp2, tmp3"), 
size = c(100, 200, 50), stringsAsFactors=F
 )

ddf <- cSplit(df, "tmp", ", ", "long")
el1 <- as.matrix(ddf[,.SD[.N>=2], by=S.no][,
                       {tmp <- combn(tmp,2)
                       list(tmp[1,], tmp[2,])},
                           by=S.no][,S.no:=NULL])

vx <-  as.data.frame(ddf[, list(size=sum(size)), by=tmp])
gg <- graph.edgelist(el1, FALSE)

V(gg)[as.character(vx[,1])]$size <- vx[,2]
plot(gg)
```